# Checking if a path exists in a boost property tree

Tags: c++, json, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

How do I check if a path exists in a property tree?

Example:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree tree;

// if path doesn't exist, put value
if (/*...*/)
{
    tree.put("my.path.to.thing", true);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple solution, you can use [get_optional()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#id792460-bb)

According to the documentation, if it exists, it returns the value otherwise it returns an uninitialized `optional`

Example

```
boost::property_tree::ptree tree;

// if path doesn't exist, put value
if (!tree.get_optional<bool>("my.path.to.thing").is_initialized())
{
    tree.put("my.path.to.thing", true);
}
```

Comment: if "my.path.to.thing" is present but not a bool then tree.get_optional<bool>("my.path.to.thing").is_initialized() returns false

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568607/boost-propertytree-check-if-child-exists provides a better answer